# error Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'aseos' available as request attribute

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, validación, thymeleaf

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de aplicar las validaciones cuando inserta registros en la base de datos.
Mi aplicación tiene una serie de clases que son:
Presupuesto que es la principal, de ella heredan ObraNueva y Reforma, y de esta última vienen Aseos y Cocina, y debo aplicar las validaciones a cada una de las clases y lo hago con una clase que implementa una interfaz de Jakarta.
Ese es el objetivo. Pero no puedo conseguirlo por el siguiente motivo:
Al hacer post del formulario de la obra, me indica:
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'aseos' available as request attribute

Sucede lo mismo al hacer post con el de cocina, y en el de aseos mi página se queda en blanco y en la consola de Eclipse veo esto:
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'cocina' available as request attribute

Qué puede estar pasando?
Os muestro mi código:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="presupuestos")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Presupuesto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected long id_presupuesto;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cliente", referencedColumnName = "id_cliente")
    protected Cliente cliente;

    protected String referencia;

    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacío")
    protected String destinatario;

    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacío")
    protected String direccion;

    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacío")
    protected String codigoPostal;

    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacío")
    protected String municipio;

    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacío")
    protected String provincia;

    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacío")
    protected String comunidad;

    @NotNull(message="No puede estar vacío")
    protected String pais;

    @Column(name = "fecha", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    protected Date fecha;

    protected double total;

public Presupuesto(long id_presupuesto, Cliente cliente, double total) {
    super();
    this.id_presupuesto = id_presupuesto;
    this.cliente = cliente;
    this.total = total;
}

public Presupuesto(long id_presupuesto, Cliente cliente, String referencia, String destinatario, String direccion,
        String codigoPostal, String municipio, String provincia, String comunidad, String pais, Date fecha, double total) {
    super();
    this.id_presupuesto = id_presupuesto;
    this.cliente = cliente;
    this.referencia = referencia;
    this.destinatario = destinatario;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
    this.municipio = municipio;
    this.provincia = provincia;
    this.comunidad = comunidad;
    this.pais = pais;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.total = total;
}
    
}
```

Esta es la clase de la que vienen todas.

Esta es la de ObraNueva:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ValidObra
@Entity
public class ObraNueva extends Presupuesto {

public static final String PREFIJO = "OBN";
public static final int PRECIO_M2 = 1100;
    
@NotNull(message = "Debes introducir un numérico", groups = ValidObra.class)
@Positive(message = "Debe ser mayor a 0", groups = ValidObra.class)
private Integer superficie;

@NotNull(message = "Introduce al menos uno de los tres valores indicados", groups = ValidObra.class)
private Double calidad;

public ObraNueva(long id_presupuesto, Cliente cliente, double total,
        @NotNull(message = "Debes introducir un numérico") @Min(value = 0, message = "Debe ser mayor a 0") Integer superficie,
        @NotNull(message = "Introduce al menos uno de los tres valores indicados") Double calidad) {
    super(id_presupuesto, cliente, total);
    this.superficie = superficie;
    this.calidad = calidad;
}

public ObraNueva(long id_presupuesto, Cliente cliente, String referencia, String destinatario, String direccion,
        String codigoPostal, String municipio, String provincia, String comunidad, String pais, Timestamp fecha,
        double total,
        @NotNull(message = "Debes introducir un numérico") @Min(value = 0, message = "Debe ser mayor a 0") Integer superficie,
        @NotNull(message = "Introduce al menos uno de los tres valores indicados") Double calidad) {
    super(id_presupuesto, cliente, referencia, destinatario, direccion, codigoPostal, municipio, provincia,
            comunidad, pais, fecha, total);
    this.superficie = superficie;
    this.calidad = calidad;
}

}
```

En el controlador tengo este código:

```
@Controller
@Validated
@SessionAttributes({ "presupuesto" })
public class PresupuestoController {

    @Autowired
    private PresupuestoService presupuestoService;

    @Autowired
    private ObraNuevaService obraNuevaService;

    @Autowired
    private ReformaService reformaService;

    @Autowired
    private AseosService aseosService;

    @Autowired
    private CocinaService cocinaService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private LocalDate fechas = LocalDate.now();

    private String annio = Integer.toString(fechas.getYear());
    private String mes = String.format("%02d", fechas.getMonthValue());
    private String dia = String.format("%02d", fechas.getDayOfMonth());

    private int nuevoPresupuesto = 0;


    @GetMapping("/shop")
    public String tienda(Model model) {
        ObraNueva obranueva = new ObraNueva();
        Aseos aseos = new Aseos();
        Cocina cocina = new Cocina();

        model.addAttribute("obra_nueva",obranueva);
        model.addAttribute("aseos",aseos);
        model.addAttribute("cocina",cocina);
        return "haztupresupuesto";
    }



@GetMapping("/finishPresupuesto")
public String finPresupuesto(@ModelAttribute("presupuesto") Presupuesto presupuesto, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();
    Cliente activo = (Cliente) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    presupuesto.setCliente(activo);

    return "encargarpresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newObra")
@Validated(ValidObra.class)
public String nuevaObra(@Valid ObraNueva obranueva, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("obranueva", obranueva);
        return "haztupresupuesto";
    }

    obranueva.setTotal(obranueva.getSuperficie() * ObraNueva.PRECIO_M2 * obranueva.getCalidad());

    nuevoPresupuesto++;

    obranueva.setReferencia(ObraNueva.PREFIJO + annio + mes + dia + String.format("%07d", nuevoPresupuesto));

    model.addAttribute("presupuesto", obranueva);

    return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newReformaAseo")
public String nuevaReformaAseos(@Valid Aseos aseos, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("aseos", aseos);
        return "haztupresupuesto";
    }

    aseos.setTotal(2 * (aseos.getLargo() + aseos.getAncho()) * aseos.getAlto()
            + (aseos.getAncho() * aseos.getLargo()) * Reforma.MANO_DE_OBRA + aseos.getPrecio_azulejo_m2()
            + (aseos.getAncho() * aseos.getLargo()) * Reforma.PRECIO_M2 + aseos.getNum_sanitarios()
            + aseos.getModif_instalacion());

    nuevoPresupuesto++;

    aseos.setReferencia(Aseos.PREFIJO + annio + mes + dia + String.format("%07d", nuevoPresupuesto) + Aseos.SUFIJO);

    model.addAttribute("presupuesto", aseos);

    return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newReformaCocina")
public String nuevaReformaCocina(@Valid Cocina cocina, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("cocina", cocina);
        return "haztupresupuesto";
    }

    cocina.setTotal(2 * (cocina.getLargo() + cocina.getAncho()) * cocina.getAlto()
            + (cocina.getAncho() * cocina.getLargo()) * Reforma.MANO_DE_OBRA + cocina.getPrecio_azulejo_m2()
            + (cocina.getAncho() * cocina.getLargo()) * Reforma.PRECIO_M2 + (cocina.getMueble_mtr_lineales() * 80)
            + (cocina.getEncimera_mtr_lineales() * 150) + cocina.getModif_instalacion());

    nuevoPresupuesto++;

    cocina.setReferencia(
            Cocina.PREFIJO + annio + mes + dia + String.format("%07d", nuevoPresupuesto) + Cocina.SUFIJO);

    model.addAttribute("presupuesto", cocina);

    return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newPresupuesto")
@Validated(ValidPresupuesto.class)
public String nuevoPresupuesto(@Valid @ModelAttribute("presupuesto") Presupuesto presupuesto, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("presupuesto", presupuesto);
        return "encargarpresupuesto";
    }

    if (presupuesto instanceof ObraNueva) {
        ObraNueva obra = (ObraNueva) presupuesto;
        obraNuevaService.save(obra);
    }

    if (presupuesto instanceof Aseos) {
        Aseos reforma_aseo = (Aseos) presupuesto;
        aseosService.save(reforma_aseo);
        reformaService.save(reforma_aseo);
    }

    if (presupuesto instanceof Cocina) {
        Cocina reforma_cocina = (Cocina) presupuesto;
        cocinaService.save(reforma_cocina);
        reformaService.save(reforma_cocina);
    }

    presupuestoService.save(presupuesto);
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/list";
}

}
```

Y esta es mi página que maneja los tres formularios al mismo tiempo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <body>
            <th:block th:insert="~{sections/background-video-2.html}"></th:block>
            <th:block th:insert="~{sections/header.html}"></th:block>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title text-center" th:text="#{shop.panel.title}"></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">                                
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <span th:text="#{shop.panel.message}" th:remove="tag"></span>
                            <br>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="obra"><span th:text="#{shop.panel.const}" th:remove="tag"></span></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id=reforma><span th:text="#{shop.panel.renov}" th:remove="tag"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">                
                <div class="col-md-12 collapse reforma">
                    <div class="panel-group">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title text-center"><span th:text="#{shop.panel.renov}" th:remove="tag"></span></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p class="text-center" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.message}"></p>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading titular aseos">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title text-center" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.panel.bath}"></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body scroll-div">
                                            <form id="formReformaAseo" th:action="@{/newReformaAseo}" th:object="${aseos}" method="POST">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <img th:src="@{/images/bano.jpeg}" style="width: 300px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.dimensions.question}"></label>
                                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                                <label class="panel-title" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.dimensions}"></label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                                <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.large}">:</label>
                                                                <input th:field="*{largo}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="largo"/><br>
                                                                <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('largo')}" th:errors="*{largo}"></div>
                                                                <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.width}">:</label>
                                                                <input th:field="*{ancho}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="ancho"/><br>
                                                                <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ancho')}" th:errors="*{ancho}"></div>
                                                                <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.height}">:</label>
                                                                <input th:field="*{alto}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="alto"/>
                                                                <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('alto')}" th:errors="*{alto}"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
        
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.toilets.message}">:</label><br>
                                                        <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="cero" value="0">
                                                        <label for="cero">0</label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="uno" value="300">
                                                        <label for="uno">1</label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="dos" value="650">
                                                        <label for="dos">2</label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="tres" value="800">
                                                        <label for="tres">3</label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{num_sanitarios}" type="radio" id="cuatro" value="950">
                                                        <label for="cuatro">4</label>
                                                        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('num_sanitarios')}" th:errors="*{num_sanitarios}"></div>
                                                    </div>
        
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.tileprice.message}">:</label><br>
                                                        <input th:field="*{precio_azulejo_m2}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="precio_azulejo" />
                                                        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('precio_azulejo_m2')}" th:errors="*{precio_azulejo_m2}"></div>
                                                    </div>
        
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.facilities.message}"></label><br>
                                                        <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="ceroM" value="0">
                                                        <label for="ceroM" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.facilities.no}"></label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="unoM" value="225">
                                                        <label for="unoM">1</label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="dosM" value="350">
                                                        <label for="dosM">2</label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="tresM" value="475">
                                                        <label for="tresM">3</label>
                                                        <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="cuatroM" value="600">
                                                        <label for="cuatroM">4</label>
                                                        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('modif_instalacion')}" th:errors="*{modif_instalacion}"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
                                            <div class="alert alert-info text-center">
                                                <p><b th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.formula.message}"></b> <br><span th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.formula.bath}"></span></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" form="formReformaAseo" type="reset" th:value="#{shop.panel.button.reset}">
                                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" form="formReformaAseo" type="submit" th:value="#{shop.panel.button.submit}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="panel panel-default" >
                                    <div class="panel-heading titular cocina">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title text-center" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.panel.kitc}"></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body scroll-div">
                                            <form id="formReformaCocina" th:action="@{/newReformaCocina}" th:object="${cocina}" method="POST">
                                                <fieldset>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <img th:src="@{/images/cocina.jpeg}" style="width: 300px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.dimensions.question}"></label>
                                                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                                                <label class="panel-title" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.dimensions}"></label>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                                <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.large}">:</label>
                                                                <input th:field="*{largo}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="largo"/><br>
                                                                <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('largo')}" th:errors="*{largo}"></div>
                                                                <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.width}">:</label>
                                                                <input th:field="*{ancho}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="ancho"/><br>
                                                                <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ancho')}" th:errors="*{ancho}"></div>
                                                                <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.height}">:</label>
                                                                <input th:field="*{alto}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="alto"/>
                                                                <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('alto')}" th:errors="*{alto}"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                
                                                    <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.furniture.message}"></label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{mueble_mtr_lineales}" class="form-control" type="number" id="muebles"/><br>
                                                    <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('mueble_mtr_lineales')}" th:errors="*{mueble_mtr_lineales}"></div>
                
                                                    <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.worktop.message}"></label><br>
                                                    <input th:field="*{encimera_mtr_lineales}" class="form-control" type="number" id="encimera"/><br>
                                                    <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('encimera_mtr_lineales')}" th:errors="*{encimera_mtr_lineales}"></div>
                
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.tileprice.message}">:</label><br>
                                                        <input th:field="*{precio_azulejo_m2}" class="form-control" type="number" step="any" id="precio_azulejo_cocina"/>
                                                        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('precio_azulejo_m2')}" th:errors="*{precio_azulejo_m2}"></div>
                                                    </div>
                
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.facilities.message}"></label><br>
                                                        <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="milCocina" value="1000">
                                                        <label for="milCocina" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.facilities.yes}"></label><br>
                                                        <input th:field="*{modif_instalacion}" type="radio" id="ceroCocina" value="0">
                                                        <label for="ceroCocina" th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.label.facilities.no}"></label><br>
                                                        <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('modif_instalacion')}" th:errors="*{modif_instalacion}"></div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </fieldset>
                                            </form>
                                            <div class="alert alert-info text-center">
                                                <p><b th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.formula.message}"></b> <br><span th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.formula.kitc}"></span></p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" form="formReformaCocina" type="reset" th:value="#{shop.panel.button.reset}">
                                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" form="formReformaCocina" type="submit" th:value="#{shop.panel.button.submit}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="panel-group collapse obra">
                        <div class="panel panel-default" >
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title text-center" th:text="#{shop.panel.const.title}"></h4>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <form id="formObra" th:action="@{/newObra}" th:object="${obra_nueva}" method="POST">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <div>
                                            <img th:src="@{/images/obra.png}" style="width: 250px; margin: auto; display: block;"><br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label th:text="#{shop.panel.cons.surface.message}"></label><br>
                                            <input th:field="*{superficie}" class="form-control" type="number" id="superficie" />
                                            <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('superficie')}" th:errors="*{superficie}"></div>
                                        </div>
            
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="calidad" th:text="#{shop.panel.cons.quality.message}">Calidad material:</label><br>
                                            <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="baja"  value="0.8">
                                            <label for="baja" th:text="#{shop.panel.cons.quality.low}"></label><br>
                                            <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="media"  value="1">
                                            <label for="media" th:text="#{shop.panel.cons.quality.medium}"></label><br>
                                            <input th:field="*{calidad}" type="radio" id="alta"  value="1.3">
                                            <label for="alta" th:text="#{shop.panel.cons.quality.high}"></label><br>
                                            <div class="alert alert-warning text-center" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('calidad')}" th:errors="*{calidad}"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                                <div class="alert alert-info text-center">
                                    <p><b th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.formula.message}"></b> <br><span th:text="#{shop.panel.renov.formula.cons}"></span></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" form="formObra" type="reset" th:value="#{shop.panel.button.reset}">
                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" form="formObra" type="submit" th:value="#{shop.panel.button.submit}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <th:block th:insert="~{sections/footer.html}"></th:block>
        </body>
    </html>

Desconozco que puede estar fallando, llevo bastante tiempo con este error y no sé cómo solucionarlo.
```

Comment: Hola Ismael, Stack Overflow no es un foro sino un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. La idea es que el problema esté encapsulado en la pregunta. Si la pregunta es más extensa que el contenido permitido, eso suele ser un síntoma de que es demasiado genérica y/o el código compartido no es un [mcve]. En lugar de añadir más información en respuestas, intenta reducir el contenido compartido para que sea todo específico al problema. Lee [ask] y sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.